# Div border in curve shape

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve div border in the convex shape and on hover it should be in normal square shape. I have added in the bottom as same I want to add on the top I tried using before but unable to achieve the result. Can anyone help me Below is my code so far I have done.
Any help will be appreciated
[image]

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.services {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 height: 420px;
 margin: 100px;
 background-color: #cccccc;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
 animation: down-bump 0.4s ease;
}
.services:before {
     
}
.serv_section {
  top: 83%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 50px 0 0;
}

.serv_inner {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  height: 25px;
}
.serv_inner:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 80px #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px; 
  content: '';
  right: -20%;
  left: -20%;
  top: -150px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.services:hover .serv_inner:after {
 top: -120px;
}

.serv_inner:before {
/*  box-shadow: 0 0 0 80px #fff;
 border-radius: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 height: 150px; 
 content: '';
 right: -20%;
 left: -20%;
 top: 130px;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; */
}

span.image_caption {
 position: absolute;
 color: red;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 font-size: 30px;
 z-index: 10;
 animation-duration: 2.5s;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
}
span.image_caption p {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    color: cadetblue; 
}
```

```html
 
<div class='services'>
  <div class="serv_section">
    <div class="serv_inner">
    
     
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right you can achieve this by simple using of different values for horizontal and vertical dimensions of the **border-radius** property (more info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius):

```css
div {
  background: grey;
  
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  
  transition: border-radius .15s ease-out;
}

/* border-radius on default state */
div {
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%/20px;
}

div:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: here I want to add elastic like rubberBand, and jello effect to the border is it possible?

Comment: The **border-radius** property can be animated too. But an effect for the border only could be tricky or will you use the effect on the hole div like [here](https://codepen.io/procodeing/pen/MwYZbQ)? That works with the border-radius too.

Comment: thanks actually I'm trying this effect https://codepen.io/alcoven/pen/raGKZy using css.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the before and after elements to make the curve, on hover hide the psuedo elements behind the element and remove the curve like this:

```css
.services {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  z-index: 0;
}
.services:hover:before{
  top: 0px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.services:hover:after{
  bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.services:before, .services:after{
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .4s;
}
.services:before {
  top: -20px;
}
.services:after {
  bottom: -20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class='services'>
  
</div>
```

Comment: here I want to use an image when I'm was add before after is on the image.

Comment: I don't understand what you say @Husna

Comment: you just add an image in the div and see on image how it will look.